# How can I speed up a loop that queries a kd-tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The following section of my code is taking ages to run (it's the only loop in the function, so it's the most likely culprit):

```
tree = KDTree(x_rest)
for i in range(len(x_lost)):
    _, idx = tree.query([x_lost[i]], k=int(np.sqrt(len(x_rest))), p=1)
    y_lost[i] = mode(y_rest[idx][0])[0][0]
```

Is there a way to speed this up? I have a few suggestions from Stack Overflow:

- [This answer suggests using Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13067268/2713263). I'm not particularly familiar with it, but I'm not very against it either.
- [This answer uses a multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856203/2713263). I'm not sure how useful this will be: my current execution takes over 12h to run, and I'm hoping for at least a 5-10x speedup (though that may not be possible).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. So would calling `tree.query(x_lost, k=...)` give me an array of `idx`? Perhaps the last line could use a list comprehension then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few notes about how you could speed this up:

1. This code loops over `x_rest`, and calls `tree.query()` with one point
   from x_rest at a time. However, `query()` supports querying multiple
   points at once. The loop inside `query()` is implemented in Cython,
   so I would expect it to be much faster than a loop written in
   Python. If you call it like this, it will return an array of matches.
2. The `query()` function supports a parameter called `workers`,
   which if set to a value larger than one, runs your query in
   parallel. Since `workers` is implemented using threads, it will likely be faster than a solution using multiprocessing.Pool, since it avoids pickling. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html).
3. The code above doesn't define the `mode()` function, but I'm assuming
   it's [`scipy.stats.mode()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html). If that's the case, rather than calling `mode()` repeatedly, you can use the axis argument, which would let you take the mode of nearby points for multiple queries at once.

Comment: This is exactly what I did! I rewrote the function in Cython, moved the `query` to a batch call, and used `scipy.stats.mode` with `axis=1`. I couldn't set `workers` sadly, since the computer cluster I'm using is on an older version of scipy, but doing this got me a 50x speedup, which was enough.